How to highlight duplicates in one row with different duplicates in another
I'm trying to highlight specific duplicates in two separate columns and for the answer to be pasted in another column.

So to clarify, if the cells in Column A match, then look into column B, if they also match then post into C, or just post once which data is repeated.
Column A can have several matches, as can column B.

What have you tried so far?  Do you have access to Office 2019 or later, which include the COUNTIFS function?

Are the columns A and B sorted in any way?

As long as your data is consistently sorted as you shown in your image I would use a combination of OR & AND statements to check the data.
I nest 2 AND statements within an OR statement to confirm that the cells above or below don't match. It first sees if the cells above are the same, then checks if the cells below are and if so take the value from column B, otherwise leave blank. Like so:
=IF(OR(AND(A2=A1,B2=B1),AND(A2=A3,B2=B3)),B2,"")

